# Yii2 составление запроса к БД с %

Tags: php, sql, yii2, symfony

мне нужно осуществить выборку из базы данных, по строке, то есть, если человек в поиске набирает словосочетание, то ему подыскиваются и комбинации
например : люблю программировать, ему подгружается так же пост со словами люблю очень сильно программировать

так вот, я написала запрос

```
return (new Query())
        ->select(...)
        ->from(...)
        ->andWhere(['like', 'bsp.text', $word])
        ->createCommand()->getRawSql();
```

перед этим я передаю word, как строку, состоящую из **слово%слово** , то есть существует отдельный метод, который вставляет % между словами

в итоговом запросе у меня неожиданно появляются слеши

```
AND (`bsp`.`text` LIKE '%слово\\%слово%')
```

отсюда рушится весь запрос

Comment: По поводу реализации такого поиска, смотрите в сторону эластика. Иначе с ума можно сойти будет, если все это реализовывать. Хотя, если проект маленький, то эластик будет избыточен. Слеши появляются из-за экранирования. Вместо вставки % между слов, лучше используйте orWhere с новым лайком и новым словом.

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder#operator-format "You may use false or an empty array to indicate the values are already escaped and no escape should be applied"

Comment: @Таня Я бы распарсил поисковое выражение на слова, а затем по кждому из них добавил `LIKE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам нужно сформировать именно такой запрос, то можно использовать `\yii\db\Expression`. Например так:

```
$word = 'word1%word2';

return (new Query())
    ->select(...)
    ->from(...)
    ->andWhere(['like', 'bsp.text', new \yii\db\Expression("'%$word%'")])
    ->createCommand()->getRawSql();
```

И получим нормальное условие без лишних слешей.

```
AND (`bsp`.`text` LIKE '%word1%word2%')
```

Но в этом случае у вас будет зависимость от порядка слов. Т.е. пост с фразой "Программировать я очень люблю" уже не покажется. Чтобы и он тоже попал в выборку, то лучше для каждого слова добавить своё условие 'like'. Например вот так:

```
$word = 'word1%word2';
$words = explode('%', $word);
$query = (new Query())
    ->select(...)
    ->from(...);

foreach ($words as $tempWord) {
    $query->andWhere(['like', 'bsp.text', $tempWord])
}

return $query->createCommand()->getRawSql();
```

Тут мы получим:

```
AND (`bsp`.`text` LIKE '%word1%') AND (`bsp`.`text` LIKE '%word2%')
```